# Open SharePoint site from another computer in the network

Tags: site-collection, alternate-access-mapping, port

I have installed SharePoint 2013 foundation in one computer and SQL in another. These two computers belong to the same network, eg.: domain1.com. But when I try to access the site from another computer, I cannot access it. The site contains 8080 port and I thought perhaps it is blocked by the firewall. So I requested to open this port in the firewall.

Now, my question is: is there another thing that I should take into account? In other words: do I have to setup something else so that I can access this from another computer or just opening the port in firewall will be sufficient?

For the moment there is no DNS host name created and I am currently opening the site using the server name: eg.: http://server1:8080

Comment: Make sure you add host file entry in the other computer to point server1 to the ip of that server

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate access mappings** enable a Web application that receives a request for an internal URL, in one of the five authentication zones, to return pages that contain links to the public URL for the zone. You can associate a Web application with a collection of mappings between internal and public URLs. Internal refers to the URL of a Web request as it is received by Office SharePoint Server 2007. Public refers to the URL of an externally accessible Web site. The public URL is the base URL that Office SharePoint Server 2007 uses in the pages that it returns. If the internal URL has been modified by a reverse proxy device, it can differ from the public URL.

Configure your URL to alternate access mapping in central admin, Give your IP address with web application port number in intranet zone, Then access your site by using your IP. similar to this

[image]